# Can't access my state after setState inside a switch-case

Tags: reactjs, switch-statement, react-hooks

i need a little help here.
I am not able to access my state after setState, both inside a case in a switch-case.
I know it is easy for someone experienced but I am a beginner with js, reactjs and react-hooks.
I spent hours burning my head to use hooks, which made it easier to call the component, but now I have this problem here.
thanks in advance! ^^

```
let ChartComponent = (props) => {

  const [chart, setChart] = useState(null)
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    switch (props.type) {
      case 'bubble':
        setChartData({
          labels: props.labels,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: props.title,
              fill: false,
              . . .
              data: props.data
            }
          ]
        })
        setChart(<Bubble . . . />)
        break

      case 'scatter':
        setChartData({ . . . })
        setChart( <Scatter . . . /> )
        break

      default:
        setChartData({ . . . })
        setChart( . . . )
        break
    }
  }, []);

  return (chart)
}

export default ChartComponent
```

Comment: It doesn't look like either chart or chartData should be state bits at all, since they're computed from props.

Comment: thanks for the response!
what should I do?
if I use a <var | let | const> chartData or <var | let | const> chart and access the variables in a normal way, I get errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for something like

```
let ChartComponent = (props) => {
  switch (props.type) {
    case "bubble": {
      const chartData = {
        labels: props.labels,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: props.title,
            fill: false,
            data: props.data,
            /* ... */
          },
        ],
      };
      return <Bubble {...chartData} />;
    }

    case "scatter": {
      const chartData = {
        /* ... */
      };
      return <Scatter {...chartData} />;
    }
    default: {
      return /* ... */;
    }
  }
};

export default ChartComponent;
```